creating webpage(HTML) with ros2 topic result. check my approach and suggest better one
Getting stream with html
    console.log("Received base64 image data");
    const imageElement = document.getElementById('streamedImage');
    imageElement.src = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${event.data}`;

Ros2 sending stream with websocket
   def start_websocket_server(self, port=3234):
        print(f'Starting WebSocket server on port {port}...')
        server = WebSocketServer('0.0.0.0', port, ImageWebSocket)
        server.websocket_clients = self.websocket_clients
        server.serve_forever()

I am working on creating a webpage demo that displays data from two ROS2 topics, image_rst (Image) and string_rst (String). Currently, my approach involves setting up a WebSocket for each topic:
image_rst (Image) -> WebSocket on port 3333
string_rst (String) -> WebSocket on port 3334
I then capture these WebSocket streams and display the results on the webpage. I am wondering if there is a more efficient or better approach to accomplish this task.
This revised version clarifies your setup and question, making it easier for others to understand and provide feedback or suggestions.
